# Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_steam_i18n_Translation-en

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic

After I start up synaptic this error message shows up. How can I fix this?

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header<br>
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_steam_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.<br>
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing lists and updating:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: It says `rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/apt/lists/partial’: Is a directory`

Comment: Try removing this one using `sudo rm -Rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/` and then execute `sudo rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*` again. Use the last command for every forlder you receive the last error